# The number $25!$ has exactly 7 trailing zeros, true or false?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I don't know how to determine it...

any hints?

Comment: How many $2$'s and $5$'s appear in $25! = 25 \cdot 24 \cdot ... \cdot 1$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint:* a zero at the end comes from the product of a $2$ and a $5$. Since the $5$'s are more rare than the $2$'s, count how many $5$'s divide the numbers $1$, $2$, ..., $25$.

Here is the result, if you want to check your work:

> $25!=15511210043330985984000000$

See also [Trailing zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_zero#Factorial).

Comment: ok, we have five 5 factors on the product, but i still cant conclude why do we have six zeros if we have more than one factor 2 on the product

Comment: @Voyager, count again, because $25$ contributes *two* $5$'s.

Comment: Oh, i forgot to count 15, sorry

Comment: why the number $5^7 \cdot 2$ have seven zeros in the end?

Comment: Well, it really doesn't, @Voyager. It only has one single zero...

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, what counts is number of factors that are equal to $5$ in the number. Assuming you don't want to count the number of fives by hand, note that for $n!$ it is given by the formula:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\log_5 n}\big\lfloor n / 5^k\big\rfloor$$
Since one out of $5$ numbers has one factor, one out of $25$ adds another, etc.. 
By way of example, although $962!$ is an enormous number, you can easily calculate that it has exactly $238$ trailing zeroes, since:
$$\bigg\lfloor \frac{962}{5}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor \frac{962}{25}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor \frac{962}{125}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor \frac{962}{625}\bigg\rfloor$$
$$=192+38+7+1=238$$